# switch statement not returning anything when condition is met

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The result of `console.log(text.length);` gives me the right value, and so does the result of `console.log(label);`

When I do this:

```
switch (label) {
    case 'Username':
        console.log('success');
        break;
}
```

I get the label i'm looking for. Here's the code:

```
import './ErrorMsg.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

const ErrorMsg = ({ label, text }) => {
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState('');
    console.log(text.length);
    console.log(label);
    switch (label) {
        case 'Username':
            switch (text) {
                case text.length > 5:
                    setMsg('SUCCESS');
                    break;
            }
    }

    return <p>{msg}</p>;
};

export default ErrorMsg;
```

It keeps returning a blank value. Any ideas?

Comment: I would generally avoid nested switch statements... it could get nasty really quickly...

Comment: Is it ok to do a switch with if statements inside of it, or is that also not great?

Comment: How many different combinations of `label` and `text` do you need to check? if this is the only case you need to check, I'd probably just use a simple `if` statement and remove the `switch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case text.length > 5` refers to either a true or false value, which would mean text would have to that value (when checking a switch statement). Therefore, you should use an `if` statement. Also, make sure to put this statement inside a useEffect, otherwise it will cause an infinite rerender loop. Below is a working implementation:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ErrorMsg = ({ label, text }) => {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");

  console.log(label, text);

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (label) {
      case "Username":
        if (text.length > 5) {
          setMsg("SUCCESS");
          console.log("HERE");
        }
        break;
    }
  }, [text])


  return <p>{msg}</p>;
};

export default ErrorMsg;
```

[image: Edit React PlayGround (forked)]

Comment: Oooh ok. Thanks dude